# Embed Google talk inside Android application

Tags: android

I am new in Android Programming and I am  trying to include GTalk application inside my application. I am trying to use XMPP server but it is not working. How can I add GTalk to my app?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know if this answer is helpful or not because the question was posted a while ago, however:

- [This sample code](http://davanum.wordpress.com/2008/12/29/updated-xmpp-client-for-android/) may solve your problem.
- [Here](http://www.andrejkoelewijn.com/wp/2008/12/30/using-google-talk-from-java-example/) you can find some sample code for using XXMP to communicate with Gtalk.
- [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4665948/android-smackapi) may also help.

Comment: I already tried the link  which u have recommended:http://davanum.wordpress.com/2008/12/29/updated-xmpp-client-for-android/ But not luck..That application is crashing