# How to get current user status and presence when login? SMACK XMPP

Tags: java, android, xmpp, smack

I make a chat application using smack in Android BEEM obviously...
the problem I facing with is that when my first user is logged in and set his status/presence
the status would persist for the other user when login...
my user status is stored in shared preference file just like BEEM did

that's why I want to fetch my currently login user's status, so that it won't be used when other user login... so the status will always new everytime the user login...

Comment: may be this will helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4665948/android-smackapi

Comment: sorry, but i think it just shows how to get presence by roster, which is in this case is the friends not the current user itself...

Comment: @user724861  What did you reach to because i need to know that too ,if you can help ?

Comment: just add a new field on your vcard, there you can set and get your current user status message lol

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Smack does not manage/remember the presence of the user for you. It only manages the presences that you receive (e.g. the ones from JIDs in your Rooster).

The easiest way is to create a reference to the last send Presence and updating that reference every time you send out a new Presence.