# QuickBlox : How to get Online Available user list

Tags: android, quickblox

I'm creating chat application using QuickBlox API, 
From the sample app i can get all list users in my account.But i want to show only the online available users. How can i retrieve the online available users?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can get the online users of the QuickBlox Chat Module through the SMACK API, using Rooster of a XMPP Connection. Check this answer.

[Can I get online users in my friend list via Smack?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4665948/can-i-get-online-users-in-my-friend-list-via-smack)

You need the online users for Chat Module or for other one?

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for your help. I got the way of solution.But one more help, How can get XMPPConnection instance from QBSession?

Answer (score 1):

Try this for online available users by using smack API.
  Roster roster = xmppConnection.getRoster();

```
  Collection<RosterEntry> entries = roster.getEntries();
  Presence presence;

    for(RosterEntry entry : entries) {
        presence = roster.getPresence(entry.getUser());

        System.out.println(entry.getUser());
        System.out.println(presence.getType().name());
        System.out.println(presence.getStatus());
    }
```

Check whether user is online(or) offline

```
  Presence presence = roster.getPresence("tom@jabber.org");
   if (presence.getType() == Presence.Type.AVAILABLE) {
       // Tom is online...
        }
```

By using  presence.getMode() method to get Mode of User. Mode is enum and its value can be chat, available, away, xa, dnd.

Answer (score 0):

XMPPConnection.addConnectionCreationListener(new ConnectionCreationListener() {

```
    @Override
    public void connectionCreated(Connection arg0) {
        Log.i(TAG, "receive xmpp connection : " + arg0);
        connection = arg0;
        roster = arg0.getRoster();

        Collection<RosterEntry> entries = roster.getEntries();
        Presence presence;

        Log.e(TAG, "user count" + entries.size());

        for (RosterEntry entry : entries) {
            presence = roster.getPresence(entry.getUser());

            Log.i(TAG, "" + entry.getUser());
            Log.i(TAG, "" + presence.getType().name());
            Log.i(TAG, "" + presence.getStatus());
        }

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as below:

1- Define a roster

```
  private SmackAndroid smackAndroid;
  private Roster roster;
```

2- Inside onCreate, initialize the smackAndroid and add XMPPConnectionListener

```
  smackAndroid = SmackAndroid.init(this);
  XMPPConnection.addConnectionCreationListener(new ConnectionCreationListener() {

    @Override
    public void connectionCreated(Connection connection) {
      roster = connection.getRoster();

    }
  });
```

3- You can add user to the roster using createEntry

```
  try {
    roster.createEntry("UserId", "userName", new String[] { "Friends" });
  } catch (XMPPException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
```

4- You can get Entries form roster using getEntry()

```
  ArrayList<String> friends = new ArrayList<String>();
  Collection<RosterEntry> entries = roster.getEntries();
  for (RosterEntry entry : entries) {
    friends.add(entry.getName());
  }
```